# Loop with the StateT monad

Tags: haskell

This is an exercise to learn the StateT monad. The program implements the game Morra. The two players are the computer and a person. The state accumulates the score of the computer and player. The program works for one iteration of function morra. However I am at a loss how to loop it. I have tried a few things but nothing seems to work.

```
module Morra where

import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Data.Char (isDigit, digitToInt)
import System.Random (randomRIO)
import Control.Monad (when)

morra :: StateT (Int, Int) IO ()
morra = do
  p <- liftIO getChar
  when (isDigit p) $
    do
      let p' = digitToInt p
      c <- liftIO $ randomRIO (1, 2)
      liftIO $ putStrLn ['P',':',' ',p] --"P: " ++ p)
      liftIO $ putStrLn ("C: " ++ show c)
      (pt, ct) <- get
      if even (c + p') then
        do
          liftIO $ putStrLn "Computer Wins"
          put (pt, ct + 1)
      else
        do
          liftIO $ putStrLn "Player Wins"
          put (pt + 1, ct)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "-- p is Player"
  putStrLn "-- c is Computer"
  putStrLn "-- Player is odds, Computer is evens."
  fScore <- runStateT morra (0,0)
  let personS = fst . snd $ fScore
      compS = snd . snd $ fScore
  putStrLn ("Person Score: " ++ show personS)
  putStrLn ("Computer Score: " ++ show compS)
  if personS > compS then
    putStrLn "Winner is Person"
  else
    putStrLn "Winner is Computer"
```

Answer (score 2):

You're 99% there. Just add `main` on a new line right after the last `putStrLn`, and `main` will call itself, effectively restarting the program.

A few tricks to simplify some things in your code:

- Use [`execStateT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Strict.html#v:execStateT)`:: StateT s m a -> s -> m s` to take just the final state of the round. This way, you don't need to use the `let` bindings to extract the score, and can do it inline instead: `(personS,compS) <- execStateT morra (0,0)`
- `['P',':',' ',p]` can be written as `("P: " ++ [p])`

It's a matter of style and preference, but you can reduce a lot of the indentation and formatting whitespace by rearranging your `if`s, `else`s and `do`s:

```
if condition
  then do
    doSomethingA
    doSomethingB
  else someFunction $ do
    doSomethingElseA
    doSomethingElseB
```

Overall, nice job :)

Comment: Thanks for that. However I need the loop on function morra. Function main is intended to run only once. If I place `morra` at the end of the function (in line with the `do` after `when`) nothing happens.

Comment: @user1897830 you need to put it inline with the `when` (indented only two spaces). If you put it inside the when, it will only loop when `isDigit p` is true. What do you mean by "nothing happens"? Does it just exit right away, or does it get stuck in a loop?

Comment: I need it to loop only when `isDigit p` is true. That is it loops until `isDigit p` is not true and then exits. However when I place `morra` inside the when it simply exits and does not loop.

Comment: @user1897830 add some `liftIO (putStrLn "Test")` in there to see exactly what is happening with the control flow. Add one that will activate when you type a character, and tell you what that character is. That way, you can find out where it is diverging from your expectations.

Comment: Ok. I did that and found out that the 2nd time through the loop the code `p <- liftIO getChar` is not being executed.

Comment: @user1897830 What do you mean "not being executed"? Put a `putStrLn` on either side of it and see what happens. Better yet, put your code in [lpaste](http://lpaste.net/)

Comment: This is what happens when I run the program after placing a `putStrLn` either side of it ("before" and "after").  The 2nd time through the loop that piece of code is not being executed.  *Morra> main
-- p is Player
-- c is Computer
-- Player is odds, Computer is evens.
before
1
after
P: 1
C: 2
Player Wins
before
after
Person Score: 1
Computer Score: 0
Winner is Person
*Morra>

Answer (score 1):

I replaced `p <- liftIO getChar` with `p <- liftIO getLine` and made a few other minor changes to allow for the fact that p is now a String rather than a Char. Now it works. Seems that it has something to do with Windows as it works using `getChar` on linux. This is the final code:

```
module Morra where

import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Data.Char (isDigit, digitToInt)
import System.Random (randomRIO)
import Control.Monad (when)

morra :: StateT (Int, Int) IO ()
morra = do
  p <- liftIO getLine
  let p1 = head p
  when (isDigit p1) $ do
    let p' = digitToInt p1
    c <- liftIO $ randomRIO (1, 2)
    liftIO $ putStrLn ("P: " ++ p)
    liftIO $ putStrLn ("C: " ++ show c)
    (pt, ct) <- get
    if even (c + p') then do
      liftIO $ putStrLn "Computer Wins"
      put (pt, ct + 1)
    else do
      liftIO $ putStrLn "Player Wins"
      put (pt + 1, ct)
    morra

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "-- p is Player"
  putStrLn "-- c is Computer"
  putStrLn "-- Player is odds, Computer is evens."
  (personS,compS) <- execStateT morra (0,0)
  putStrLn ("Person Score: " ++ show personS)
  putStrLn ("Computer Score: " ++ show compS)
  if personS == compS then
    putStrLn "No Winner"
  else if personS > compS then
    putStrLn "Winner is Person"
  else
    putStrLn "Winner is Computer"
```